# Curl --data command usage

Tags: linux, curl

I am using the following command for getting the website data,

**curl --data '{"xxxNamespace": "xxxxxx", "h_xxx_action": "xxxxx"}' -i -u username/password -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json" -X GET**

I would like to download the webpage. But this command results in some html value as o/p,

```
**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**
Date: Sat, 01 Oct 2016 15:32:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Content-ID: -75f83766:15766e71efd:6afa
Set-Cookie: CRN=showWelcomePage%3Dtrue%26automaticPageRefresh%3D30%26displayMode%3Dlist%26useAccessibilityFeatures%3Dfalse%26columnsPerPage%3D3%26linesPerPage%3D15%26timeZoneID%3DWET%26productLocale%3Den%26listViewSeparator%3Dnone%26showOptionSummary%3Dtrue%26showHiddenObjects%3Dfalse%26contentLocale%3Den%26format%3DHTML%26skin%3Dcorporate%26; Domain=.xxx-xx.com; Path=/xx
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Kindly help me with the command, Am I doing something wrong ? 
I tried with -X GET Option as well, but it returned the same o/p. Kindly help

Comment: You're seeing the HTTP headers because you're using the `-i` command line option.  If you don't want that, don't use it.  See `man curl` for details.

Comment: Tried with -i option but got the same o/p without the http OK ,set-cookie part. I just want to download the page content. Kindly help

Comment: Sorry for the typo...tried without -i..but still getting same result.